# Convert an integer array to string array in Julia

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, julia

Is there a way to convert an array of integers (or any numbers) to an array of strings in Julia? Essentially, I want to convert `[1 2 3 4]` to `["1" "2" "3" "4"]`.

Stuff that doesn't work:

```
numbers = [1 2 3 4];
strings = ["1" "2" "3" "4"];
string(numbers)
convert(Array{String}, numbers)
```

Output:

```
"[1 2 3 4]"
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type String
...
```

I'm using Juila 1.3.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surprisingly, this doesn't appear to be a duplicate.

For a single number, you use the `string` function. For an array of numbers, you need to broadcast the `string` function to each element of the array. The simplest way to do this in Julia is using the `.` syntax, e.g.:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = string.(x)
```

Note, broadcasting works for any function (including user-defined functions). So, e.g.:

```
f(x) = x^2
f.([1,2,3,4])
```

just works.